# Share on Facebook - Post to Wall dialog

Tags: android, facebook, share, sharing

I have 3 buttons for sharing: Facebook, Twitter, Email:
[image: facebook share]

I want when the user presses the Facebook button to show up the `Post to Wall` dialog, like below:
[image: facebook share]

is there any way to do that? I guess that, first the user must log-in in his Facebook account and that that post to wall dialog should appear.

Any help? :)

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done directly. What you have to do is to integrate the Facebook SDK for Android, and then use the Post to Wall dialog.

You should go through this official tutorial which explains elaborately.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/authenticate/

Hope this helps.